# Is it possible to receive text messages (SMS) using ethereum?

Tags: dapps

Is it possible to build a dapp that can receive sms text messages?

Answer (score -1):

https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://status.im/&grqid=_JCn42gQ&hl=en-IN

Yes. There already exists an application named **status** 
It used whisper. You can download alpha version of it and try.

Comment: Does it allow for sms? It looks like it's just for messaging but not actual sms text messages

Comment: No, you can't use it to send SMS. It runs on Ethereum's P2P Whisper protocol, which isn't compatible with SMS.